# Variable size swap file for CentOS/Fedora

Tags: centos, fedora, swap

Is there any way how to create dynamically growing / shrinking swap file for CentOS / Fedora distributions?

I know of project [SwapSpace](http://pqxx.org/development/swapspace/) that is for Debian family and pretty dead.

Comment: As written in their presentation document, this has serious performance drawbacks.  Considering the price of disk space, you should get another disk and assign a sufficiently large swap file or partition.  No system can overcome the performance limitation involved, not even Windows which was probably the first to implement this.  It will typically either cause a temporary lockup or some programs will crash.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that there is a fork : https://github.com/Tookmund/Swapspace . Note that since this is kernel-related it doesn't matter much what Linux distro/family you are running it on.